# Expiring session on browser close

Tags: django

I've read that you can put the following line of code in settings.py to expire a user's session on browser close:

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

I've implemented this, but when I close the browser, I can reopen it and the user is still logged in. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto your settings.py and add the following constants in the file

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 5 # 5 seconds for testing
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

You will logout on inactive/idle for 5 seconds.

Comment: This doesn't work for Chrome as Chrome runs in the background even when the browser is closed, but this is a great start. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Some browser like chrome allow user to navigate in case of re-opening however you can try with set_expiry() 
See :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: - You can also try with browser close event.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiousity, where or what file would I place the set_expiry() perameter?

Comment: Try where you are validating credentials

Comment: Second solution is : use SESSION_COOKIE_AGE and SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST in settings.py

Comment: Validating credentials? You mean my login view?

Answer (score 0):

First try this as they're recommended:
Put these configurations in your `settings.py`:

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 600 # set just 10000 seconds to test
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

As mentioned in above answer you can use `set_expiry(value)`
When `value` is 0, i.e. `request.session.set_expiry(0)` then your session will be logged out when you close the browser. 
Like in the snippet i have, i'm trying to log user out at every 5 minutes but you set it to 0:

**`views.py`**

```
def login_user(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            request.session.set_expiry(300)
            login(request, user)

            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')                
            return redirect('blazon:index')
            # return render(request, 'blazon/index.html', {'projects': projects})
        else:
            return render(request, 'blazon/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'blazon/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
return render(request, 'blazon/login.html')
```